How to color in flextable with an as_grouped_data format with equal cells with same values
I have this dataset and I am trying coloring with the same color,cells with same values, after using as_grouped_data(., groups = "") function.
dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  A = c("NHH","NHH","NHH","NHH",
        "NHH","NHH","NHH","NHH","NHH","cUU","cUU","cUU",
        "cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU",
        "cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU"),
  B = c("uJc","GBY","rYv","hYl",
        "hat","hqL","jxF","hqL","VMg","gWX","Vae","uJc",
        "GBY","Vae","hYl","uJc","pEI","gWX","ZCY","ZCY","Vae",
        "Vae","rYQ","veT","hqL","Vae","hYl","QIN")
)%>% as_grouped_data(., groups = "A")


cid <- dplyr::consecutive_id(dat$B)
cols <- sample(colors(), size = length(unique(cid)))
mycolors <- cols[cid]


flextable(dat) |> 
  bg(i = 1:nrow(dat), j = 'B', bg = mycolors, part = 'body')

I am noticing that color generated like are randonly chosen and thus there some like black and similar which are too dark to color the cells with. Is it possible to fix this issue somehow?

Without a reproducible example, it's harder to help. I will only use your data and the first column to demo:
dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 A = c("NHH","NHH","NHH","NHH",
                       "NHH","NHH","NHH","NHH","NHH","cUU","cUU","cUU",
                       "cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU",
                       "cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU"),
                 B = c("uJc","GBY","rYv","hYl",
                       "hat","hqL","jxF","hqL","VMg","gWX","Vae","uJc",
                       "GBY","Vae","hYl","uJc","pEI","gWX","ZCY","ZCY","Vae",
                       "Vae","rYQ","veT","hqL","Vae","hYl","QIN")
)

cid <- dplyr::consecutive_id(dat$A)
cols <- sample(colors(), size = length(unique(cid)))
mycolors <- cols[cid]
  
  
flextable(dat) |> 
  bg(bg = mycolors)


To answer your updated question, here is a code. Note as_grouped_data() output should be used with as_flextable(), not flextable(). Here, there is one single color that highlight repeated cells.
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  A = c("NHH","NHH","NHH","NHH",
        "NHH","NHH","NHH","NHH","NHH","cUU","cUU","cUU",
        "cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU",
        "cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU","cUU"),
  B = c("uJc","GBY","rYv","hYl",
        "hat","hqL","jxF","hqL","VMg","gWX","Vae","uJc",
        "GBY","Vae","hYl","uJc","pEI","gWX","ZCY","ZCY","Vae",
        "Vae","rYQ","veT","hqL","Vae","hYl","QIN")
) %>% as_grouped_data(., groups = "A")
z <- dat |> 
  mutate(
    cid = case_when(
      !is.na(B) ~ consecutive_id(B),
      TRUE ~ NA
    )
  ) |> add_count(cid)


as_flextable(dat) |> 
  bg(i = ~!is.na(B) & z$n > 1, j = 'B', bg = "yellow", part = 'body')


Ok. Actually I would be rather interested on coloring the second column. But It principal is the same, then I will try hour codr

Hi. There is a little change. Actually I have just the essential part of using as_grouped() function.

You took the answer and used it to totally change your question. That's surprising

Hi just realized later on that actually the problem I was facing was due to that element of flextable. But if you not agree with it, feel free to downvote the question, delete your answer or whatever else you want to do.

I would not downvote... It's just makes the answer absurd as it does not answer the new question.
